# Remove the asterisk from "Your flagging history"

Tags: feature-request, status-norepro, flag-history

In the flag history, the following sentence is preceded from an asterisk, but the asterisk is not used in the flag history, and the sentence is always shown:

> older flags were not recorded valid/invalid

[image: screenshot]

The asterisk should be removed, in this case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since this text no longer exists on the flag history page, I'm going to [status-norepro](/questions/tagged/status-norepro) this so this no longer lingers as an active request.